# convert a normal map to height map with imagemagick: how to recreate/integrate following algorithm

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a tangent space normal map to a height/displacement map. For sure this will be not 100% accurate speaking in terms of "exact height" for each pixel. But the relative height from each pixel to the next is more than enough.

Available Algorithm + Info's: 
http://www.cournia.com/devnull/n2h/n2h.pdf

Questions:
1. How to convert a normal-to-height map in Photoshop/Gimp? Is there a way using these tools? Beside; I don't wan't to use CrazyBump or any other Texture-Tools. This has to run via CL later on. A Photoshop solution is more or less just a pre-step to understand workflow a bit better.

2. If not possible with PS/Gimp; how to include the algorithm in an imagemagick process?
3. I've checked already Doom3:-Normal2Height; Crazybump & all other texture tools like Nvidia's PS-Plugin, xNormal, Awesomebump, SSBump, etc. I'd need this function working with Imagemagick.

Any help is very much welcome. Python preferable.
thx

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities for doing that with **ImageMagick**.

Firstly, you could implement your own *process* module. When running `configure` to install **ImageMagick**, you would then do:

```
./configure --with-modules=yes
```

Then, when you want to apply your bumpmap processing on the command-line, you would do:

```
convert input.png -process analyse <param1> <param2> result.png
```

Your processing needs to be written in C/C++ and the best description I know of is on Alan Gibson's webpages [here](http://im.snibgo.com/customim.htm).

Secondly, you could write your entire processing using **Magick++** which is the C++ binding to **ImageMagick**. Best description I know of is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) with sample code [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html).

Comment: Thank you Mark. I'll take a deeper look into it. Any further tips+tricks are very welcome.